# Segueing between views causes CALayer position contains NaN: [305 nan]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I'm attempting to navigate from on view controller to another but when I preform the segue I get the following un caught exception:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', 
reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [305 nan]'
```

I'm using the following code to do the segue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToGameFromIntro" sender:self];
```

Comment: What is happening in that segue? Is it custom or one of the default like push and modal?

Comment: I actually figured out what the problem was. There was a divide by zero in the viewDidLoad for the second view controller.